# Delphi library Path for components

Tags: delphi

In Delphi (Berlin), I create a new win32 package and component. I compile it and it creates the default Unit Output Directory of .\$(Platform)\$(Config). Now after installing I need to set the System Library Path correctly so that I can use it in new applications.  Should I set this to the dcu path (.\$(Platform)\$(Config))?

If I do, I then need to compile the component for each variant of platform and Config that needs to be supported [(Win32/Win64)/(DEBUG/RELEASE)].

Is this correct? Maybe it would be better to always point to the RELEASE path?

Comment: It all depends on which dcus you want to be used

Comment: Or, maybe I should just point it to the source code. This has the advantage of being able to make modifications to the component as the component then get compile with each project it us used on in whatever platform/config the project is using.

Comment: It depends on what your needs are. You decide.